# Very strange Mingw64 (C++) bug when readinig from a file inside a function?

Tags: c++, ifstream, mingw-w64

so I've been experimenting with OpenGL recently, and I've gotten to the point where I want to read shaders from files. Now, when I run the following [minimum reproducible example], it works fine in 'debug mode' (-O0):

```
#include <fstream>

void read(const char* filename) {
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(filename);
}


int main() {
    read("example.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run it with any optimizations (O1 though to O3), it causes a segfault. I am thinking that this is a bug with Mingw, as it also works inline with optimizations.

I am very confused. If anyone knows why this is happening then that would be greatly appreciated :)

I am on windows 11

EDIT: as noted by @Konrad Rudolph, my mingw is outdated. I will update this question with the results

Comment: It’s virtually impossible that the code you’ve posted is causing a segfault. The error is elsewhere. If this is is indeed all the code you have, how are you compiling and running it? What version of MinGW are you using?

Comment: @KonradRudolph That is the entirety of my code as it's minimum reproducible form, and I have tested it with both `g++ test.cxx` (works fine) and `g++ test.cxx -O2` (fails). As I said in my answer, it works inline (ie., not moving it to a separate function), which makes it all the more peculiar.

Comment: @KonradRudolph hmm... Actually, maybe my mingw *is* outdated. It says 2018, so idk: g++.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Still, Windows has exceptional backwards compatibility. Windows 11 should run a 2018 executable without problems. That's not really outdated.

Comment: It is very strange, but I may as well try it.

Comment: Could you also show where it crashes, and the kind of crash (exception code)?

Comment: I think it is to do with the version of mingw, but upgrading it's probably more work that switching to using the C file API. Thanks a lot anyway! (I'll also create an answer if I get anything working with the C++ fstream library though)